# Structuring one-to-one interdocument relationship MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-design, schema

I'm just starting out using MongoDB and I'm a bit lost at how to structure my documents to tackle the following problem (note this is just a basic example that matches what I'm having difficulty with).

### The Problem:

Let's say I have a top-level document called `Family`, these documents are stored in a collection called `families` and contain some basic information about a family, i.e.

```
{
    _id:        ObjectId("foobar"),
    familyName: "Simpson",
    address:    "743 Evergreen Terrace, SpringField",
    children:   [
        {
            _id:           ObjectId("barfoo"),
            firstName:     "Bartholomew",
            preferredName: "Bart",
            middleName:    "JoJo"
        }
        // ... etc.
    ]
}
```

Now, let's say I'm adding another top-level document to my application: `School`, stored in a collection called `schools`. I need to relate each child to their school, and each child may only attend one school at any point in time. How would I approach this in Mongo? I've come from a very heavy RDBMS background and I'm having a bit of difficulty figuring this out. The main issues that I've come up against in my solutioning revolve around the fact that I'll need to **efficiently** handle the following use-cases:

- View a school and be able to see all Children enrolled there
- View a family and see all of the Schools that their children are enrolled in

### What I've tried:

#### Storing the child references in the `School`

The first solution I went with was to make a `enrollments` array in my `School` document which referenced the `_id` of a child as well as their full name for convenience, i.e.

```
{
    _id:         ObjectId("asdadssa"),
    name:        "Springfield Elementary",
    enrollments: [
        {
            child_id: ObjectId("barfoo"), // Bart Simpson
            fullName: "Bart Simpson" // concatenation of preferredName and familyName
        }
    ]
}
```

This seemed fantastic for the first use-case, which just needed to display all of the students enrolled at a particular school.

However when I turned to the second use-case I realised I may have made a mistake. How on earth would you figure out which school each child in a `Family` belonged to? The only way I could see would be to actually traverse every single school in the `schools` collection, drill down into their `enrollments` and see if the child_id matched a child in the family...doesn't seem very efficient does it? That led to my next attempt.

#### Storing a reference to the school in a child object

Because each child can only belong to one school I figured I could maybe just store a reference to the `School` document in each child sub-doc, i.e. Bart's document would now become:

```
{
    _id:           ObjectId("barfoo"),
    firstName:     "Bartholomew",
    preferredName: "Bart",
    middleName:    "JoJo",
    school_id:     ObjectId("asdadssa")
}
```

Now the *second* use-case is happy, but the first is unsatisfied.

### Conclusion

The only way I can see both use-cases being satisfied is if I employ both solutions simultaneously, i.e. store the `school_id` in the child sub-doc and also store the `child_id` in the `enrollments` array.

This just seems clunky to me, it means you'll need to do at least two writes per enrollment change (to remove from the school and change the child). As far as I'm aware MongoDB only has atomic writes and no transaction support so this looks like a place where data integrity could potentially suffer.

If any MongoDB gurus could propose an alternate solution that'd be great. I'm aware that this particular problem really screams "RDBMS!!!!", but this is only a small part of the application and some of the other data really lends itself to a document store.

I'm only in the planning stage now so I'm not 100% committed to Mongo, but I thought I'd give it a crack since I've been hearing some good things about it.

Answer (score 0):

For the small use case that you've described, I would switch up the `families` collection to a `people`  or `students` collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("barfoo"),
    "family_id" : ObjectId("spamneggs"),
    "name" : {
        "first" : "Bartholomew",
        "last" : "Simpson"
    },
    "school_id" : ObjectId("asdadssa")
}
```

that stores students as separate documents but unites them with a common `family_id` (I also snuck in another way to store names). Schools can just have school information without enrollments. I'll give example code in the mongo shell for your two use cases. To find all the children enrolled in Bart's school and Bart's school's document:

```
> db.students.find({ "school_id" : ObjectId("asdadssa") })
> db.schools.find({ "_id" : ObjectId("asdadssa") })
```

To find all of the schools Bart's family has children enrolled in:

```
> var schools = []
> db.students.find({ "family_id" : ObjectId("spamneggs") }, { "_id" : 0, "school_id" : 1 }).forEach(function(doc) {
        schools.push(doc.school_id)
    })
> db.schools.find({ "_id" : { "$in" : schools } })
```

Both of these are simple application-side joins and should work fine in your case because one family won't have zillions of children. Indexes on `school_id` and `family_id` will help.

For writes, only the student document needs to be updated with the proper `school_id`.